# WOPI - Business User term clarification

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, ms-wopi

I am investigating adding Office Online support to a product using WOPI to allow its users to view and edit office files.

While reading the WOPI docs there is a section on '*Editing*' and it introduces the concept that a user (of my system) can be either a 'Consumer' or a 'Business User'

**My question is**: What means one of the users using my system needs to be flagged as a 'Business User' in the WOPI Api in relation to the table in this section of the docs ->
http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#editing-office-files

I can't seem to find a definition for the term 'Business User' in the WOPI context (unless I have missed it. :) )
I need to understand so I know if my users need a 365 subscription or not in order to edit files and for which users I need to set the ['Business User' placeholder](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html?highlight=business#term-business-user) in the action url's to 1 for.

I would have thought that all of the users using my system are consumers as they pay to use it, or is it case of:

- Consumer = Joe Public, single user
- Business User = Employee of company paying to use my system (In which case all my users are 'Business Users')

Thanks.

Comment: Can you quote the part that is unclear to you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's the meaning of 'Business User' from the table in this section of the docs -> http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#editing-office-files

If the user is a 'Business User' then the `BUSINESSUSER` placeholder in the action url's is set to `1`, but I'm a little confused as to what makes a user a business user.
I would have thought that all of the users using my system are consumers as they pay to use it, or is it case of:

Consumer = Joe Public, single user
Business User = Employee of company paying to use my system

In which case all my users are 'Business Users'

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: @canters were you able to figure out the difference between those two types of users.

Comment: @Lexnim - No I don't believe I did. Sorry. I not longer work for the same company anymore and don't have access to the final implementation. Hope you are able to resolve your issue.